# How can I execute a block to populate a variable only if the variable is blank?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, idioms

I have some instance methods in a class that must be called in a sequence. The failure of any method in a sequence will require the previous method to be re-called. I'm storing the result of each successful method call in a class variable:

```
class User
  @@auth_hash = {}
  def get_auth_token
    result = MyApi.get_new_auth_token(self) if @@auth_hash[self]['auth_token'].blank?
    if result['Errors']
      raise Exception, "You must reauthorize against the external application."
    else
      @@auth_hash[self]['auth_token'] = result['auth_token']
    end
    @@auth_hash[self]['auth_token']
  end
  def get_session_id
    result = MyApi.get_new_session_id if @@auth_hash[self]['session_id'].blank?
    if result['Errors']
      get_auth_token
      # Recursion
      get_session_id
    else
      @@auth_hash[self]['session_id'] = result['session_id']
    end
    @@auth_hash[self]['session_id']
  end
end
```

I would like to get rid of those conditionals, but don't know how to perform the block only if there are errors present in the returned hash.

Comment: It looks like the first line of `get_session_id` will generate an infinite recursion if your condition is met - is that how it's actually written?

Comment: I just cobbled this together to simulate what I really have, but that conditional will not execute if result['Errors'] is nil.

Comment: What is `@@auth_hash` all about? Using class variables is usually a sign something's very wrong with your design. Are you using it as some kind of cache here? That's usually counter-productive, the cache only applies in one process, of which there are usually many, and you have no invalidation code here.

Comment: I'm trying to use it as some kind of cache from AR. This all runs from one background process. I would love to know a better way, believe me. I've got writer's block after looking at this too long.

Comment: @tadman I am against "Using class variables is usually a sign something's very wrong with your design", but in the OPs case, it does smell wrong because the OP has not shown it used in any class method.

Comment: @AKWF Have you considered  Zach Kemp's comment? That infinite recursion seems useless.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually a mistake.

Comment: @sawa Virtually every time someone's using class instance variables directly, they should be using class methods that access them and act as a thin abstraction layer. Your class should not have its state manipulated by instance methods themselves, it just makes things messy and too inter-dependent.

Comment: `result => nil` when `if @@auth_hash[self]['session_id'].blank? => false`.  Do you want that?  If not, fix that and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole method requires a rewrite...but to answer your question, why wouldn't the following work?

```
my_proc = ->(){ fill_me_with_something }
my_var ||= my_proc.call

raise StandardError if my_var.nil?
```

Editing my answer to better answer the question...The syntax:

```
 my_proc  =   ->(a,b){ a + b }
```

Is another way to express a block, for all intents and purposes:

```
 my_proc(1, 5)   #=> 6
```

You can also express Procs in this format:

```
 my_proc = Proc.new{ |a, b| a + b }
```

The advantage of using a Proc is that you can set your block-like behavior to some variable, and then invoke `call` on that proc whenever you want, which, in your case, is when some other variable is blank.

Comment: Thanks Dan! There are things on that first line I don't recognize: If you had to write that first line in English, how would you say it? I understand the assignment and the block, but the "->()" is a mystery to me.

Comment: That's short hand for a Proc...so another way to write it is:  
 
    my_proc = Proc.new{|val|  puts val}    (eh screw it, just going to edit my answer)

Comment: I love this. I never knew that shorthand, thanks a whole lot!